# Eclipse RCP integration tests: Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: maven, integration-testing, rcp, tycho

If I build our maven/tycho project on windows, everything runs fine.
If I build on linux (OpenSuse 15), the integration tests immediately fail with this message

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

But: even on the linux machine, I can run the built product without any problems.
Does anybody know where the problem could be here?
I use a target platform which is set to the eclipse 2020-03 build.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the reason for this was in the pom.xml of the integration-test plugin:
If you add line breaks to the properties=>ui.test.vmargs element, then it only works on windows, but on linux it will not.